# Angular Error With NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular

I have a problem with this error(
NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true') and I do not know how to fix it.

I want to use global loading animation in root component and use service to control it.

**appcomponent**

```
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div *ngIf="showLoading$ | async" >Show Loading Animation</div><router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  showLoading$ = this.appService.getLoadingObservable();
  constructor(private appService: AppService) {}
}
```

**appservice**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppService {
  private loading$ = new BehaviorSubject(false)

  setLoading(value: boolean) {
    this.loading$.next(value)
  }

  getLoadingObservable() {
    return this.loading$.asObservable();
  }
}
```

**anothercomponent**

It's a component in lazy load module which send loading to service.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, tap, delay } from 'rxjs';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-another',
  template: `
  <div>{{ content$ | async }}</div>
  <button (click)="requestNewContent()">request</button>`,
})
export class AnotherComponent {
  getContent$ = new BehaviorSubject('');
  content$ = this.getContent$.pipe(
    tap(() => {
      this.setLoading(true);
    }),
    delay(1000),
    tap(() => {
      this.setLoading(false);
    })
  );
  constructor(private appService: AppService) {}

  setLoading(value: boolean) {
    this.appService.setLoading(value);
  }

  requestNewContent() {
    this.getContent$.next(new Date().toString());
  }
}
```

Here is a stackblitz demo.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ah4ber?file=src/app/another.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using a BehaviorSubject (`getContent$ = new BehaviorSubject('');`), which will immediately emit a value (even before view rendering of the component and starts the pipe execution.

This will then set the loading value to true (async) and results in the error shown in your question (first it was false, but after rendering it was "magically" set to true).

In order to resolve this issue, the easiest way would be to switch to a `Subject` instead of a `BehaviorSubject`. This way no initial value would be emitted (which from what I can tell is not needed in your case).

Comment: I tried to switch to a Subject instead of a BehaviorSubject, but the error was still existing. This will then set the loading value to true (async) inspired me and I tried to
add observeOn(asyncScheduler) pipe before this.setLoading(true) pipe in content$. The error is resolved.

Comment: What do you mean? Please try to open your stackblitz example and switch only `getContent$` to a Subject instead of a BehaviorSubject. You will see that the error is gone.